# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<myDB.Models.Image>'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, entity-framework, icollection

I have converted `modelfirst` to `dbfirst` ASP MVC project
I have parent child tables `Albums` and `Images`
in `modelfirst` code was as below which was working fine

```
*Album Model*
public class Album
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage = "{0} can not be greater than {1} chars")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Image> Image { get; set; }
}

*Controller*
ViewBag.Albums = db.Albums.
           .Select(c => new
           {
               Album = c,
               Image = c.Images.OrderBy(i => i.sort)
           })
           .AsEnumerable() // not execute yet
           .Select(a => a.Album)
           .OrderBy(a => a.sort)
           .Take(6)
           .ToList();

*view*
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Albums)
{
    if (item.Images.Count > 0)
    {
       default_image = item.id + "/" + item.Images[0].img;   //this line has error after changing to dbfirst                                     
       *Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<myDB.Models.Image>'*
    }
}
```

Please notice difference changes in model below model is generated automatically by loading from database through edmx

```
*Album model*
public partial class Album
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Album()
    {
        this.Images = new HashSet<Image>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

the only change in both versions (Model-first and DB-first) is in Album Model
that is this line (IList/ICollection)

```
public virtual IList<Image> Image { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
```

I changed it to iList, it worked but after updating other table from database through edmx this again updated to `ICollection`

Comment: You're sending an anonymous type to the view, not an `Album`.

Comment: How can I solve, Please